# Sign-in with Microsoft identity provider fails, works for other providers

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Sign-in with Microsoft identity provider fails, works with others

I have an `Azure AD B2C` tenant with a `SingIn and SignUp` policy that I hope to use 
for user management with an Angular2 SPA.

The policy is configured for three `identity providers`:

- Google
- Microsoft
- Email Signup

When I use the `Run Now` button in the Azure portal to run this policy, I get the default Sign In dialog, and I can sign in with either `Google` or `Email signin`.  (By that I mean I get re-directed to my app's redirect page as I expect.)  However, when I try to sign in using the `Microsoft`
provider, I end up at an error page with the following address:

`https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.&state=StateProperties%3deyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6NDcyMmQyNjItOTk1Yi00YTJlLWFmNWUtODkwNDgyODlhMzM0IiwiVElEIjoiM2Y2ZDVmNjAtMDdiNC00ZDA3LWEyZDItN2U3YWQwOWRhOGQ5In0`

I see that the problem is related to an invalid `redirect_uri`. But I thought the `redirect_uri` was an application-level setting shared by ALL identity provders that I have configured. Why does my `redirect_uri` setting work for `Google` and `Email signup`, but not for `Microsoft`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I noticed the message and it does not help.  I am under the impression that the redirect_uri setting is shared by all identity providers configured for the policy, including Google and Email providers that work fine.  Is there anything specific to the Microsoft identity provider that I can configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure your Microsoft application with the right redirect URL.

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-msa-app):

> Enter https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}/oauth2/authresp in the Redirect URIs field. Replace {tenant} with your tenant's name (for example, contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com).

Why you have to do this: (courtesy of Chris Padgett)

> The redirect URI that is configured in the Azure AD B2C Portal represents the reply address for your client application. This is so Azure AD B2C can return an ID token to your client application. The redirect URI that is configured in the Application Registration Portal represents the reply address for your Azure AD B2C tenant. This is so the Microsoft Account identity provider can return a security token to your Azure AD B2C tenant.

So, your app is federating authentication to Azure AD B2C.
B2C then further federates to the Microsoft Account identity provider.
So when a user a logs in with a Microsoft account, they are sent back to B2C with a token, which B2C validates.
If all is okay, they are signed in to B2C, and sent back to your app.
So you see that from the point of view of the MSA identity provider, B2C is the client.
So the redirect URL there must point to B2C.

Comment: juunas thanks! That certainly solved my problem.  I am still a bit unclear though on what is the purpose of having to specify the redirect URI in two places: (1) in the Microsoft application portal and (2) in the B2C tenant.  How do these two "redirect uri" settings play together?  Do they have to be the same?

Comment: Hi @ebhh2001. The redirect URI that is configured in the Azure AD B2C Portal represents the reply address for your client application. This is so Azure AD B2C can return an ID token to your client application. The redirect URI that is configured in the Application Registration Portal represents the reply address for your Azure AD B2C tenant. This is so the Microsoft Account identity provider can return a security token to your Azure AD B2C tenant.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris :) I edited my answer to include details on this.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Thanks.  In the Application Registration Portal, I see there is a way for having multiple "Redirect URLs".  When would I need multiple Redirect URLs, if ever?

Comment: Hi @ebhh2001. It isn't uncommon for applications that have multiple host names to have multiple reply URLs such as `https://login-east.contoso.com` and `https://login-west.contoso.com`. When you register a B2C application, you can register multiple reply URLs for it, as described by [Azure Active Directory B2C: Register your application](https://login-west.contoso.com).

Answer (score 1):

As the document stated, you should Enter `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}/oauth2/authresp` in the Redirect URIs field.

> But I thought the redirect_uri was an application-level setting shared
>   by ALL identity provders that I have configured. Why does my
>   redirect_uri setting work for Google and Email signup, but not for
>   Microsoft?

You're right, the redirect_uri is an applicaiton-level sttings. It should be same in  all IDPs redirect URIs. But this Redirec URI is set by Azure. NOT your applicaiton. **It means that your can use other IDPs to login to your app with AAD B2C, NOT login to your applicaiton directly**. So, the `redirect_uris` must be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}/oauth2/authresp`, not the `redirect_uri` in your application itself.

**URI doesn't equal URL**. The redirect URI is just  a unique identifier to which Azure AD will redirect the user-agent in an OAuth 2.0 request. It's not redirect URL, Azure AD authentication endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` use redirect URIs to check where it should be responsed. Aslo, it can be same as the URL as the endpoint. Here should be the same I guess.

Summary, you need use the unique redirect URI `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}/oauth2/authresp`for all IDPs , not just Microsoft account.

Hope this helps!